# php: sort array in alphabetical order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array `$skills` and I need to sort it in alphabetical order:

```
array:172 [▼
0 => Skill {#1135 ▼
-id: 1
-skill: "AngularJS"
}
.........
12 => Skill {#1184 ▼
-id: 13
-skill: "CoffeeScript"
}
```

I am trying to use

```
usort($skills, "cmp");

    public function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["skill"], $b["skill"]);
}
```

but I get

```
Warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'cmp' not found or invalid function name
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Would you mind doing a `print_r($skills)` before the sort and posting an edit to your question with the result. Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are in a class definition, so you would have to use: `usort($skills, [$this, "cmp"]);`